# I want the value in "self.q" in my Swift program to be printed to xcode console as well

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I want the value in `self.q` in my Swift program to be printed to the Xcode console as well. How to go about it? I am very new to Swift.

```
let receivedQ = json["q"].stringValue
self.q = receivedQ
print(self.q)
```

Comment: `print(self.q)` is exactly how you go about it, how is it not working?

Comment: I think he means that he wants a "label" to print, so the output of that would act like: `print("self.q: \(self.q)")`.

Comment: You will have to provide us with enough code to execute it. We need to know the type of  `json` and the type of `q` in order to provide any help. Please edit your question to provide some more context. This _is_ as you might know Swift and we _need_ the types, we do not fight them as in `JavaScript`.

Comment: I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, this is not possible in Swift. The language has no way of querying the text representation of an expression, and there's no no preprocessor to help you do that.